# Realm filter not taking Int64 as parameter

Tags: swift, realm

I have an Object with `Int64` as ID:

```
class MyObject : Object {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int64>();
}
```

And I want to filter a `List` of `MyObject` using this ID:

```
let objectID = myObject.id.value;
let object = myObjectsList.filter("id = \(objectID)").first; // crash
```

The App crashes with the error:

```
'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type int for property 'id' on object of type 'MyObject', but received: Optional(2)'
```

When i instead do:

```
let object = myObjectsList.filter("id = \(myObject.id.value)").first; // crash
```

The error is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unable to parse function name 'Optional:' into supported selector (Optional:)'
```

And when I do:

```
let object = myObjectsList.filter("id = \(myObject.id)").first; // crash
```

The error is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unable to parse the format string "id = RealmSwift.RealmOptional<Swift.Int64>"'
```

So how am I supposed to filter my objects using the objects id?

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
let object = myObjectsList.filter("id = %@", objectID ?? NSNull()).first
```

It's worth highlighting that Swift's `\(someVariable)` string interpolation and `NSPredicate`'s `%@` argument substitution syntaxes are *not* interchangeable. The former inserts a string representation of the variable into the predicate string, which `NSPredicate` then parses. Using `%@` substitutes a reference to the object into the resulting `NSPredicate` object. This difference explains why you're seeing errors parsing the predicate format string in two of your attempts.

The second thing to be aware of is that since queries are represented by `NSPredicate`, an Objective-C type, the substituted arguments need to follow its conventions. In particular, Swift optionals cannot be used to represent the presence or absence of a value as Objective-C is not aware of optionals. Instead, a non-optional type can represent the presence of a value, and an instance of `NSNull` represents the absence of a value. In the code above I used `??`, Swift's nil coalescing operator, to achieve this mapping.

Comment: Hi. Thx for your answer but this is also not working: `reason: 'Expected object of type int for property 'id' on object of type 'MyObject', but received: 2'` But what worked was: `filter("id = \(objectID! as Int64)");`